# Why does basic assembly code fail to be build?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, visual-studio-code, x86, masm

I have a big problem, I just started with assembly, and I think I at least have understood the basics of `MOV` and the system calls, but I cannot really understand why do not my codes want to be build and just run, they are the basic 'Hello World' commands
My code looks like this

```
    global_start

_start:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msg
    mov edx,len
    int 0x80

    mov eax,1
    int 0x80

segment .data
msg db 'Ide Gas na max', 0xa
len equ $ - msg
```

I  tried to set up all different environments, ,MESM32 SDK, Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code with `MASM/TASM` extension which opens DOSBOX, sadly the it crashes instantly and debug option gives error for every line, (I did learn that TASM is more for 16bit applications, so I changed to MSAM only in preferences)

```
    main.ASM(1): error A2008: ression : segment
    main.ASM(2): error A2008: ression : global_start
    main.ASM(4): error A2034: values for structure
    main.ASM(16): error A2088: ring
```

I did not include full error, because only those 4 variations repeat for each line, I can post if you want to see, but I do not want to make this too long. So then I thought maybe it is just wrong set of instruction I used,  so I just found random [hello world codes](https://montcs.bloomu.edu/Information/LowLevel/Assembly/hello-asm.html) online and just copy and pasted and absolutely none worked, always there was an error  And then I changed the IDE, to MASM32 editor, which only always gives "Assembly Error" and Visual Studio just says every time diff message which I have no idea now what is, I deleted it, I just do not like it really, and yes I did set up MASM for the VS project also, I set it up following more tutorials, and also I have some book I followed.
So please, can someone explain me what do to, what to try, I am clueless, in the code I also tried `Section` instead of `Segment` or just changing orders or dots, still nothing

Comment: This is Linux assembly code!  The `int 0x80` is the tipoff.  You can't copy and paste random assembly; you need an example that is adapted for the particular OS, architecture, and assembler that you are using.  It's not like Java or Python or even C, where the same code is portable to all platforms.

Comment: This is NASM syntax, and even then you're missing a space between `global` and `_start`.  (So you'd get a warning when linking with `ld`, but it would still pick the top of the `.text` section as the entry point.)  Building it into a Windows executable would not be useful, though, because it uses the `int 0x80` Linux system-call ABI.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know, I aprecitate it, Tell me maybe, where I can find some easy to read list of all MASM system calls and syntaxes ?